# Accessing STL Map element using [] operator adds new element if key does not exist

Tags: c++, stl

In windows OS I am accessing STL Map element using [] operator adds new element with default value  if key does not exist. How to avoid that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

int main ()
{
  std::map<char,std::string> mymap;

  mymap['a']="an element";
  mymap['b']="another element";
  mymap['c']=mymap['b'];

  std::cout << "mymap['a'] is " << mymap['a'] << '\n';
  std::cout << "mymap['b'] is " << mymap['b'] << '\n';
  std::cout << "mymap['c'] is " << mymap['c'] << '\n';
  std::cout << "mymap['d'] is " << mymap['d'] << '\n';

  std::cout << "mymap now contains " << mymap.size() << " elements.\n";

  return 0;
}

Output:
mymap['a'] is an element
mymap['b'] is another element
mymap['c'] is another element
mymap['d'] is
mymap now contains 4 elements
```

.

Access to element 'd' adds new element in the map and initialized to its default value.How to avoid adding new element when accessing element?

Comment: Use `find` instead of `[]`. `[]` on a map is convenient, but it returns a reference to the value in the map. So if no map entry exists it must create it in order to have that reference.

Comment: What do you want to happen if the element is not there?

Comment: @juanchopanza- I just dont want to add new element in the map when accessing element if key does not exist. Since in my code  when checking the size of map, it gives size as non zero, it fails my logic.

Comment: i am also curious what else you did expect to happen when the element is not yet in the map. In other languages you would get an exception, but C++ isnt that trigger-happy with exceptions, they are reserved for exceptional cases

Comment: @usermgs you can accept my answer if you are satisfied with it. :)

Answer (score 2):

Use the map's `find` member function when you want to find out whether an object is already in the map.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <string>

template <class Map, class Key>
void show(Map const &map, Key key) {
    auto pos = map.find(key);
    if (pos == map.end()) {
        std::cout << "key: '" << key << "' was not found\n";        
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "key: " << key << ", value: " << pos->second << "\n";
    }
}

int main ()
{
    std::map<char, std::string> mymap {
        { 'a', "an element" },
        { 'b', "another element" }
    };

    mymap['c'] = mymap['b'];

    show(mymap, 'a');
    show(mymap, 'b');
    show(mymap, 'c');
    show(mymap, 'e');

    std::cout << "mymap now contains " << mymap.size() << " elements.\n";

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `find` instead of `[]`. Like this: `map<char, std::string>::iterator it = mymap.find('a')`.
Find will return an iterator pointing to the object that has the key that you used to find. The object is a pair object consisting of the key and value. So, you can access them by `it->first` (key) and `it->second` (value).

If the key is not found in the map, then it will return `end()` iterator that indicates the end of the map. So you can check the iterator if it is equals to `mymap.end()`.

```
map<char, std::string>::iterator it = mymap.find('a');
if(it == mymap.end()) {
    //not found
}
else {
    /* 
    found, it->first holds the key which will be 'a', 
    in this case and it->second will hold "an element" for your case. 
    */
}
```

Comment: @usermgs you can accept my answer if you are satisfied with it. :)